# tmutil inheritbackup fails

Tags: backup, time-machine, migration

I lately moved my world to a new MacBook Pro: Apple silicon, Mac OS Sonoma 14.2.1. I'd like to maintain continuity with my Time Machine backups on the older computer (Mac OS Catalina, Intel based). Following other answers on this list, I tried a tmutil inheritbackup with unfortunate results:

```
% sudo tmutil inheritbackup /Volumes/MyBook/Backups.backupdb/Ken’s\ MacBook\ Pro 
Failed to inherit machine store at '(null)', error: Error Domain=TMStructureErrorDomain Code=7 "Structure has wrong type" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Structure has wrong type}
```

I assure you, this is the volume on which my old Mac has been backing up successfully for ages.  And I assure you, this volume was not tampered with in the process of bringing up the new computer, except to delete some unrelated files to make room.
Here's the relevant portion of its file system. Incidentally, I don't find anything with the .sparsebundle designation anywhere. Was that an older format?

Any insights greatly appreciated. Is the distance between the two operating systems to great? Is the move to Apple silicon a showstopper?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem and for me worked changing extended attributes manually:

1. I first started a backup process and waited for new directory to appear and interrupted the process.
2. Then I used `xattr -l *` inside `Backups.backupdb` to get the values of extended attributes.
3. I decided to copy `com.apple.backupd.BackupMachineAddress` and `com.apple.backupd.HostUUID`, maybe only one of them is enough. So I noted down values for those keys for the newly created backup directory.
4. I deleted the new backup.
5. I used `sudo xattr -w ATTRIBUTE_NAME ATTRIBUTE_VALUE OLD_BACKUP_DIRECTORY` for every attribute to assign new values for old backup directory.
6. After that `sudo tmutil inheritbackup PATH_TO_OLD_BACKUP_DIRECTORY` succeeded.